# Adding a .ajaxForm function to standard .ajax call

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

So I'm trying to find a method of getting a progress bar working on my .ajax call but not having much luck. I know that the ajaxForm plugin has the following code in it that allows for the uploadProgress option but the way my code works I'm not able to use that plugin. Is there anyway of adding the following code somehow so that it attaches to the standard .ajax call? Long shot I know!

```
// XMLHttpRequest Level 2 file uploads (big hat tip to francois2metz)
function fileUploadXhr(a) {
    var formdata = new FormData();

    for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        formdata.append(a[i].name, a[i].value);
    }

    if (options.extraData) {
        var serializedData = deepSerialize(options.extraData);
        for (i=0; i < serializedData.length; i++)
            if (serializedData[i])
                formdata.append(serializedData[i][0], serializedData[i][1]);
    }

    options.data = null;

    var s = $.extend(true, {}, $.ajaxSettings, options, {
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        type: method || 'POST'
    });

    if (options.uploadProgress) {
        // workaround because jqXHR does not expose upload property
        s.xhr = function() {
            var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload) {
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                    var percent = 0;
                    var position = event.loaded || event.position; /*event.position is deprecated*/
                    var total = event.total;
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                    }
                    options.uploadProgress(event, position, total, percent);
                }, false);
            }
            return xhr;
        };
    }

    s.data = null;
        var beforeSend = s.beforeSend;
        s.beforeSend = function(xhr, o) {
            o.data = formdata;
            if(beforeSend)
                beforeSend.call(this, xhr, o);
    };
    return $.ajax(s);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure what framework(s) are you using, but the upload progress callback is very simple set like this: `XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress = function() {alert(Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total)+"%");};`

Comment: Basically, I have my upload script and it is using a .ajax call and I am trying to get a progress bar on it whilst the ajax call is running.

Comment: I understand. Maybe you should try to assign the callback without `.addEventListener` method, just like  have posted - using `=`.

Comment: Not sure I understand you

Answer (score 0):

I do not guarantee on that, but try this:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }
                console.log("Progress: "+percent+"%");   //debug to see if the problem is there
                options.uploadProgress(event, position, total, percent);
            };
```

From posted code, I cannot even guess if the problem is in `onprogress` event handling or that `options.uploadProgress`, whatever it is.
I posted this as answer only because it wouldn't fit in comment.